# WSGI Error in apache2 using Two different python version (Django App)

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am trying to set up two Django app on Apache2 server in ubuntu using different python version(2.7 and 3.5).

apache conf:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess site1  display-name=%{GROUP} 
WSGIScriptAlias /site1 /var/www/bigb/site1/site1/wsgi.py
    <Location /site1>
        WSGIProcessGroup site1
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    </Location>
WSGIDaemonProcess vdms display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIScriptAlias /vdms /var/www/bigb/vdms/vdms/wsgi.py 
    <Location /vdms>
        WSGIProcessGroup vdms
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    </Location>
    <Location /site1>
        WSGIProcessGroup site1
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    </Location>
   <Directory /var/www/bigb/vdms/vdms>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/bigb/site1/site1>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
```

Wsgi.py file for site1:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
sys.path.append('/var/www/bigb/site1')
sys.path.append('/var/www/bigb/site1/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]= "site1.settings"
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Wsgi.py file for vdms:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
sys.path.append('/var/www/bigb/vdms')
sys.path.append('/var/www/bigb/vdms/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]= "vdms.settings"
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When i tried to run apache server i can able to access site1 , but when i tried to load vdms I get internal server error

```
 raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Tue Aug 07 11:25:03.426115 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12920] [remote 192.168.1.14:57874] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Tue Aug 07 11:25:03.426095 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12920] [remote 192.168.1.14:57874]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Tue Aug 07 11:25:03.426100 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 12920] [remote 192.168.1.14:57874]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 81, in populate
```

I have installed both libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 and libapache2-mod-wsgi on my system and I have installed mod_wsgi in venv also. can I add two LoadModule in configuration or Is there any configuration error so I made. Please educate me to solve this problem

Comment: Go back in the log and find the original error. The "populate() isn't reentrant" error is a subsequent error that occurs on attempt to reload the WSGI script file after it has failed to load once. So you must find first error after restart.

Comment: One major problem you will have though is one Apache instance can't be used to host both Python 2.7 and 3.5 virtual environments at the same time. This is because mod_wsgi is compiled for a specific Python version and you can't force it to use a virtual environment for a different version.

Comment: Is there any solution @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: Is it possible by using a different port for 2 application?

Comment: No, using different ports doesn't help. The mod_wsgi module links to the Python shared library and it is not possible to link two different versions of the shared library into one process. Your only choice is to use mod_wsgi-express running as separate application and proxy the front end Apache to it.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton , Will you please share me some documentation ..

Comment: On what in particular? There is a whole site out their with mod_wsgi documentation at http://www.modwsgi.org. You can also find details about mod_wsgi-express on PyPi at https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/. Search on blog at http://blog.dscpl.com.au you will find further information there on mod_wsgi-express.

Comment: Graham I want to know how to configure using mod_wsgi-express. What are the steps should I need to follow. @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177783/discussion-between-selvakumar-and-graham-dumpleton).

Comment: can I use normal mod_wsgi for One application and mod_wsgi-express for another application @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: Yes. Read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/proxying-to-python-web-application.html and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/07/redirection-problems-when-proxying-to.html Just ignore that it talks about Docker. The setup of Apache for proxying is the same.

Comment: Hi Graham, I have used mod_wsgi-express in one of my application.  Following Command "mod_wsgi-express start-server wsgi.py --port 81 --host 192.168.1.21 --user www-data --group www-data --server-name 192.168.1.21"
.  It works fine in localhost but after configuring host and server name I get an error ---> Client denied by server configuration /tmp/mod_wsgi-192.168.1.21:81:0/htdocs

Comment: There is no need to use ``--host``, and ``--server-name`` should only be used if you are wanting to use HTTPS and have a SSL certificate generated for that host name, and you are only accessing the site via that host name in any URL. The server name should not be an IP address either.

Comment: Brilliant thanks Graham, I really want to buy a beer for you. Its working

Comment: Both my application working fine graham.Thanks for your support, Now how to run mod_wsgi-express application run automatically when system start.@GrahamDumpleton

Comment: That depends on your operating system. See the ``setup-server`` option in https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/ Then integrate running ``apachectl`` in that for start/stop from your ``systemd`` or whatever is being used.

Comment: I had configured `setup-server`. When I run `apachectl` manually application is running properly.  But when I run using supervisor during OS start. I get `RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant` with permission denied 'tmp/db37abc.... ' . I think the database is not available at runtime. Is there any solution That would help me.@GrahamDumpleton

Comment: When using mod_wsgi-express is defines a default ``startup-timeout`` of 15 seconds. If the WSGI application cannot be loaded within that time, processes will be restarted. This works around transient issues which cause Django setup to fail resulting in that ``populate() isn't reentrant`` error.

Comment: Do be aware that ``populate() isn't reentrant`` error is a subsequent error, and not root cause of problem. You need to find the first error in the logs after processes startup. Not sure if that is what you are referring to as permissions problem. If you are using SQLite, be aware that database file and directory must both be writable to user Apache runs your code as.